# How to set EditText 'Hint' and 'Password' property programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating a login form for my Android app, i make a single layout for both create account and login, on button click i want to change edit text hint property from 'enter user name' to 'Re enter username' and also want to change other edittext password property to true can any one help me how to change both property from code dynamicaly i saw all methods of edit text but not found any clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use .setHint() method on either your TextView or EditText.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint(int)

EditText is an extended class of TextView. Hence, most of the methods (if not all) of TextView will work well with EditText.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at its parent class [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html), specifically [`setHint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28int%29) and [`setInputType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType%28int%29).